# What is the best structure for app using ngrx?

Tags: angular, ngrx

Structure 1

```
reducers
   index.ts //Combine all reducers
   user.reducer.ts
   product.reducer.ts
actions
   index.ts  //Combine all actions
   user.action.ts
   product.action.ts
effects
   index.ts //Combine all effects
   user.effect.ts
   product.effect.ts
selector
   //Combine all selectors
   user.selector.ts
   product.selector.ts
```

OR

```
user
  user.reducer.ts
  user.action.ts
  user.effect.ts
  user.selector.ts
product
  product.reducer.ts
  product.action.ts
  product.effect.ts
  product.selector.ts
reducers.ts //Combine all reducers
actions.ts //Combine all actions
effects.ts //Combine all effects
selectors.ts //Combine all selectors
```

Comment: Can you add some  more comments with your code

Comment: I personally like the first approach. It's the structure that the ngrx team uses in their example app. Other then that, you have one more folder for interfaces or classes and it can often happen that you use the same interface on more then one reducer. You also often use the same actions on more then one effect and so on. That's why i prefer the first structure.

Comment: I'm not sure there is really an ideal way to do this. The style guide (now way out of date) says to separate the store from the component based upon SRP.  This is a bit dubious because your component is going to be more than tightly coupled to the state and store implementation... So moving it to it's own folder creates an artificial sense of decoupling.  I've yet to see a good state management system that plays nicely with angular that doesn't have some massive downsides.

Comment: I really like the simplicity of Akita for managing state, but at the heart of it the questions are the same:  namely what is the best folder structure and separation of concerns.

Answer (score 19):

I have found the first structure to suit well for a rather small app when using reducers, actions or others in several SMART components in an app.

Although it promotes the separation of concerns, I have found it rather tedious to jump between the various directories.

Usually, working with, i.e, `user.reducer.ts`, would involve working with the other files: effect, actions etc. So, the 2nd approach seems a bit more tidy.

I would like to suggest a 3rd structure that may fit and one which follows the "barrel" approach in angular2:

```
- store
    - user
        - index.ts
        - user.actions.ts
        - user.effects.ts
        - user.reducer.ts
        - user.reducer.spec.ts

    // the store definition file - will expose reducer, actions etc..
    // for connecting those to the app in the bootstrap phase
    - index.ts
```

With this structure, the **user** directory is a barrel which exposes the various logics components which can be imported separately just by importing the user, i.e:

```
import { reducer as UserReducer } from '../store/user'; 
// or
import { UserReducer } from '../store/user'
```

I'm experimenting with these approaches in my open source media player app - [Echoes Player](http://echoesplayer.com) - http://github.com/orizens/echoes-player
As mentioned in another comment, these strategies and architecture applied to echoes player are compiled in the [ngrx styleguide](http://github.com/orizens/ngrx-styleguide)

Comment: This is what i thought as well.

Comment: I am leaning the same way. However, the big problem with feature based division (for me) is that some of the features depend on others. Each time it happens I break my head as to how split them up the cleanest.

Comment: This is the default structure when using the ngxs schematic starter kit - https://github.com/ngxs/schematics

Comment: When I used this structure, which I otherwise like a lot, I ended up with circular import warnings, when effects from one feature were using actions from another and vice versa due to barrel files in each feature. How to avoid this? I have not found a better solution rather than placing actions into actions/ folder, effects into effects/ folder and reducers into reducers/ folder with barrel files for each.

Answer (score 3):

I follow this guide for best ngRx practices and structure:

https://github.com/orizens/ngrx-styleguide

The second way you mentioned is the best because (quoting from the style guide):

> **DO** create separated files in the reducer's directory for: reducer, reducer's spec, reducer's actions and reducer's selectors. Finally, use index.ts as a barrel for exporting each file's content.
>   **Why?** it's easier when developing to locate each relevant class/file