# What is the best folder structure for ngrx when lazy loading is used Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I have an Angular 6 app where lazy loading is used.  My folder structure looks like this:

```
src
  app
    main
      products
      invoices
      customers
      suppliers
    core
      header
      footer
      services
      core.module.ts
    shared
    app-routing.module.ts
    app.component.html
    app.component.css
    app.component.spec.ts
    app.component.ts
```

I followed the recommended folder structure for lazy loading (here, each folder under the `main` folder is its own module section).

If I want to incorporate `ngrx`, I have seen differing opinions as to where to include the store, reducers, etc.  One article I read said to add a `store` folder and include all of the ngrx pieces in there.  Another article I read said to add the ngrx pieces to each module/section.

There is another stackoverflow article here: [What is the best structure for app using ngrx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38497719/what-is-the-best-structure-for-app-using-ngrx) that talks about ngrx folder structure, but no mention of lazy loading.

Is there a recommended way to structure ngrx when lazy loading is used?  Does it make more sense to add a store with reducers, actions, etc. to each module or to make one giant store folder with everything in that?  This app is not too big; it's more of a medium sized application.

Thanks!

Comment: We have an example with a suggested folder structure using lazy loading here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-NgRx-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Demo5

Comment: @DeborahK, this is an excellent example!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely add the ngrx pieces to each module separately. It gives you a good structure and every module is self-contained. Furthermore, the ngrx store in each module can be lazy loaded as well, so the state will only be there if you are loading the module.

Further details here: https://medium.com/@AnkurRatra/lazy-loading-of-modules-with-ngrx-store-4th-version-angular-2-23c93295d4e8